# Java Calendar + TimeZone

Tags: java, android, calendar

встретился с такой проблемой, которую не понимаю как решить...

С сервера прилетает дата добавления в таком вот виде: "2020-10-15T11:51:51.000Z"
Время указано по нулевой часовой зоне

На самом же деле добавление произошло не в 11:51, а в 14:51, так как я (добавляющий) нахожусь в +3 часовой полосе.

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
cal.time = sdf.parse(item.time) // "2020-10-15T11:51:51.000Z"
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev")

val sdf2 = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())

Log.i("LOG", sdf2.format(cal.time))
```

В итоге в логе у меня 11:51, а по идее должно быть 14:51...

Что я делаю не так?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы уверены, что должны применять метод `setTimeZone()`  к `cal`? На мой взгляд логичнее было бы применить ее к sdf:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());

calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(item.getTime())); 

sdf.setTimeZOne(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev"));

Log.i("LOG",sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
```

sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
cal.time = sdf.parse("2020-10-15T11:51:51.000Z")

```
val sdf2 = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
sdf2.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev")

val dateString = sdf2.format(cal.time )

println(dateString)
```

Вот так вот! Спасибо AVRamones за наводку